# Is there a way to search for organizations that have no active relationships?

Tags: relationships, advanced-search, organization

We're working on cleaning up database records, and while it's easy to pull individual records with no activity, I'm not sure how to find organizational records that are not tied to any current individuals. Is there a way to do this through Advanced Search?

Answer (score 2):

Search for organisation contact using advance search who have relationship. Add those contact into a smart group.

Now find contact using Include/Exclude custom search or search builder, with contacts not in above created smart group.

Comment: I wish this would work for me. I can't get smart group criteria to save properly, so it keeps giving me a smart group of 2 instead of 2085 (the initial results page). And without being able to create a group to search against, I'm not sure how I'd be able to run the include/exclude search.